# retrieve data from xml and insert into sqlite

Tags: xml, sqlite

I receive xml files daily, all files have same structure, i want to retrieve data from xml files and insert into my sqlite database table,
I can read data from xml file using php script which give me html file in this format

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [versione] => FPR12
        )

```
[FatturaElettronicaHeader] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [DatiTrasmissione] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [IdTrasmittente] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [IdPaese] => IT
                        [IdCodice] => 04220520235
                    )

                [ProgressivoInvio] => 0001
                [FormatoTrasmissione] => FPR12
                [CodiceDestinatario] => KRRH6B9
                [ContattiTrasmittente] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [Telefono] => 0458240144
                        [Email] => info@validus.it
                    )

            )

        [CedentePrestatore] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [DatiAnagrafici] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [IdFiscaleIVA] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [IdPaese] => IT
                                [IdCodice] => 01280930528
                            )

                        [CodiceFiscale] => MNCMNL78B56F592A
                        [Anagrafica] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Denominazione] => MANCIANTI EMANUELA
                            )

                        [RegimeFiscale] => RF04
                    )

                [Sede] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [Indirizzo] => VIA DI POGGIO GOLO
                        [NumeroCivico] => 12
                        [CAP] => 53045
                        [Comune] => Montepulciano
                        [Provincia] => SI
                        [Nazione] => IT
                    )

                [Contatti] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [Telefono] => 3477969531
                        [Email] => info@cantinachiacchiera.it
                    )

            )
```

now how can i insert this file or data into my database table, or any other way to retrieve data from xml to sqlite database?

Answer (score 0):

```js
<?php
$path = "yourfilepath.xml";
$xml=simplexml_load_file($path) or die("Error: Cannot load language file");
foreach($xml->children() as $Futureelectronic) {    
       $index = (int)$Futureelectronic->datatransimition['idtransmition'];
       $value = $Futureelectronic->idpaece;
       $data = array_fill($index,1,$value);
       echo $data[$index];
       echo "<br>";
}

?>
```